# ¿Como convertir query de sql en linq?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Requiero convertir la siguiente query a linq

```
select * from detalle_pedido
where articuloid = 13555 and id_pedido=13
```

lo he intentado de la siguiente manera

```
var querydetalle = _db.detalle_pedido.Where(dt => dt.articuloid == articu.articuloid || ped.id_pedido == idpedido);
var dtp = querydetalle.FirstOrDefault();
```

pero no logro obtener el valor que debería obtener. Que debo modificar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos errores:

1. El operador para AND es `&&` no `||`
2. La variable a la que debes comparar el idpedido es `dt` no `ped`

Debería quedar así:

```
var querydetalle = _db.detalle_pedido.Where(dt =>
    dt.articuloid == articu.articuloid &&
    dt.id_pedido == ped.idpedido);
var dtp = querydetalle.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

En tu consulta el operador que estas utilizando es OR debes utilizar && para que te funcione y luego listar los valores en una lista, tu codigo quedaria asi,

```
  var querydetalle = _db.detalle_pedido.Where(dt => dt.articuloid == articu.articuloid && det.id_pedido == ped.idpedido).ToList();

return querydetalle;
```

Answer (score -1):

El operador que estás utilizando || es OR en expresiones LAMBDA el operador para AND es &&. Tu consulta quedaría así:

```
  var querydetalle = _db.detalle_pedido.Where(dt => dt.articuloid == articu.articuloid && ped.id_pedido == idpedido);
  var dtp = querydetalle.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: No solo en expresiones lambda sino en cualquier expresión booleana

Comment: Gracias por responder, la he probado de esa forma. Pero me obtiene otro registro con el mismo `articuloid` pero con diferente `id_pedido`